# Create Hierarchical tree with nodes name as str

Tags: python, class, tree, xlsxwriter

I need to create tree showing calculation of formula at each level. I receive data in as dictionaries

```
level1={'Operating Cash Flow':['Total Revenue','Operating Expenses']}   
level2={'Total Revenue':['Net Income','Change in Asset'],'Operating Expenses':['Non Cash Expense','XYZ']}
```

And So on. Idea is to create complex trackers using publicly available data. And then output(in excel) it in a hierarchical format to show it's calculation. Something like this

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                       Operating                       |
|                        Cash Flow                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|                           60                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|         Total Revenue        |    Operating Expense   |
+------------------------------+------------------------+
|              10              |           50           |
+------------------------------+------------------------+
| Net Income | Change in asset | Non cash Expense | XYZ |
+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+
| 20         | -10             | 40               | 10  |
+------------+-----------------+------------------+-----+
```

So I tried to make a tree like structure for this.

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.score=0
        self.fields=[]
        self.weights=1
        self.children=[]

    def add_child(self,obj):
        self.children.append(obj)
        self.weights= self.weights + obj.weights -1

    def enter_score(self,value):
        self.score=value
```

where Node.fields will store their fields and Node.children points to there value. Since field names in dict are str, I am not sure how to make this complete tree. Also any help regarding how to output this as excel after tree is done would be helpful.